# Bug with pixel access in OpenCV 2.x

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I'm having trouble trying to find out how to access rgb pixel in the new version (2.x) of OpenCV. I tried using a mix of the old and the new method but without success.

Here is my code

```
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
Mat img;


string winMain = "Main";

img = imread(argv[1]);

for (int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
    {
        img.data[j * img.cols + i * 3 + 0] = (uchar)0; //B
        //img.data[j * img.cols + i + 1] = (uchar)0; //G
        //img.data[j * img.cols + i + 2] = (uchar)0; //R
    }
}

namedWindow(winMain);

imshow(winMain, img);

waitKey();  

return 1;
}
```

As you can notice in the following example, only a third of the image is modified.

[Link to example](http://imageshack.us/a/img832/7083/20120917123426main.jpg)

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested out your code, and I found the bug. You multiplied the **column index** by 3 (`i * 3`), but it's also necessary to multiply the **row index** by 3 (`j * img.cols * 3`).

I replaced `j * img.cols` with `j * img.cols * 3`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
    {
        img.data[j * img.cols * 3 + i*3 + 0] = (uchar)0; //B
        //img.data[j * img.cols * 3 + i*3 + 1] = (uchar)0; //G
        //img.data[j * img.cols * 3 + i*3 + 2] = (uchar)0; //R
    }
}
```

**Let's try an example.**

Example image (from [MIT pedestrian dataset](http://cbcl.mit.edu/software-datasets/PedestrianData.html)):

[image: original img]

Result using OP's code:

[image: OP's code]

Result using the revised code (with `j * img.cols * 3`):

[image: New code]

Comment: You are right, I mistakenly assumed that the OP was just looking for any way to access the pixel. Your answer is more appropriate.

Comment: It was obvious. I know that the code is not optimized, but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop, you can do:

```
img.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[0] = 0;    // Blue Channel
img.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[1] = 0;    // Green Channel
img.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[2] = 0;    // Red Channel
```

Is this what you wanted or I understood incorrectly?

Comment: This will work. (I tested it out and confirmed.) Some people say that the `at()` operator is slower than using direct pixel access (e.g. `img[index]`). I'd be curious to see an empirical study that compares the overhead for `img.at()` and `img[]`.