# conversion between c++ class and OpenCV matrix operation

Tags: c++, opencv, for-loop, matrix, type-conversion

I am trying to convert the following c++ line into OpenCV matrix operation (which is also c++):

```
double myCode::calculate ( int i, int au )
{
    double k;
    for ( int j = 0; i < N; i ++ );
    {
         k += fabs(data[i][j] - means[au][j]);            
    }
}
```

I want to define "data" and "means" as openCV matrix type, like:

```
cv::Mat data ( NUMBER_OF_OBSERVATIONS, N, CV_8UC3 );
cv::Mat means = cv::Mat.zeros ( 5, N, CV_8UC3 );
```

then repeat the above class for this cvMat type "data" and "means". How can I do that? Especially I don't know how to do the line:

```
k += fabs(data[i][j] - means[au][j]);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It might make sense to remove the `;` on the line where the `for` loop starts. Also, `cv::Mat.zeros` should actually be `cv::Mat::zeros`

Comment: I mistakenly write ";" here but in my code there was no ";" in the for loop line, besides I replaced "cv::Mat.zeros" with "cv::Mat::zeros" but the "fabs" function still could not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write

```
double myCode::calculate ( int i, int au )
{
    cv::Scalar res = sum(avg(data(RowRange(i)) - means(RowRange(au))));
    return res[0] + res[1] + res[2]; // sum all the channels together
}
```

Note that `RowRange()` is not actually the correct syntax - look in OpenCV docs for the proper usage of `Range()`, but that's the idea.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it says "sum" is undefined. But I've already included "math.h", together with "stdio.h". This might be too low leveled error, but I still couldn't fix it. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: sum is from opencv core try cv::sum(cv::abs(...))

Comment: thank you again. I replaced "sum(avg(...))" with "cv::sum(cv::abs(...))", but now it says "no suitable conversion function from cv::Scalar to double exists". I think cv::sum returns a cv::Scalar, but my class is of double type. I need your help again, thank you.

Comment: A little look in the docs would help you... but anyway, I will correct the function. Some other errors are expected - please check the docs for the correct usage of Range()

Comment: I've checked and used as "cv::Mat.rowRange", and also changed the class type from "double" to "cvScalar", and it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to access pixels in OpenCV `Mat` objects is with the `at()` operator.
If your data type were 1-channel unsigned char (`CV_8UC1`), you could simply do this:

```
k += fabs(data.at<uchar>(i,j) - means.at<uchar>(i,j)); //works for CV_8UC1 type
```

However, you have 3 channels (R, G, B), dictated by the `C3` in your `CV_8UC3` datatype. So, here's how do your `k += fabs(...)` on each channel individually:

```
//for CV_8UC3 type
k += fabs(data.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] - means.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0]); // Blue Channel
k += fabs(data.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1] - means.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1]); // Green Channel
k += fabs(data.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2] - means.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2]); // Red Channel
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463677/bug-with-pixel-access-in-opencv-2-x) offers further explanation about pixel access.

Comment: I tried your code, but it says: "Vec3b" is not defined. Do you have any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Try declaring `using namespace cv;` at the top of your `.cpp` file, or else replace `Vec3b` with `cv::Vec3b`.

Comment: I replaced `Vec3b` with `cv::Vec3b` in the code above. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I tried and that error seems to be solved, but not it doesn't recognize "fabs". It says: more than one instance of overloaded function "fabs" matches the argument list.

Comment: The line `k += fabs(data.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] - means.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0]); // Blue Channel` compiles for me. I'm guessing the "doesn't recognize `fabs`" is an issue with header files. Here are the relevant headers that I'm using: `#include <stdio.h>` `#include <stdio.h>` `#include <math.h>`

Comment: I am also including the same header files with you. I even tried removing out the headers one by one, but still couldn't find the error here. In the "math.h" file, there were two "fabs" functions, one for "float" and the other for "double" datatype. Do you have any idea? Thank you again.

Comment: Can you just try doing `int x = 1; int y = fabs(x);` and see if it compiles?

Comment: No, " int x = 1; int y = fabs(x) " does not compile either.

Comment: Aha, I think I figured it out. `fabs()` likes floating-point (float or double) data types. I think the compiler is complaining because `fabs` isn't really defined for char data. I think casting to a double should fix it:

`fabs((double)data.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] - (double)means.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0]);`

Comment: yes, you are right, it compiles with your new code now, thank you :)